# Delete a key in a JSON object, and add a different key

Tags: python, json

So, at one point in my AWS Lambda function (python), I have a JSON object like this:

```
[{"a":1, "b":2},
{"a":3, "b":4},
{"a":5, "b":6}]
```

Now, from this JSON object, I want to remove the `a` key from all, and want to add a constant `c` key to all.

I.e my final JSON object should look like this:

```
[{"b":2, "c":10},
{"b":4, "c":10},
{"b":6, "c":10}]
```

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj = [{"a":1, "b":2},
{"a":3, "b":4},
{"a":5, "b":6}]

new_obj = [{ **{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k != "a"}, # remove "a" key
             **{"c":10}} # add "c" constant
             for d in obj]

print(new_obj)
# [{'b': 2, 'c': 10}, {'b': 4, 'c': 10}, {'b': 6, 'c': 10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse through the list and use the pop command to remove the a key. The below code should help you do that as well as add the constant c key to all

```
for dict_obj in obj:
    dict_obj.pop('a', None)
    dict_obj['c'] = 10
```